# How to set Vue component that is imported globally to have preset attributes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For example, I'm using [vue-numeric](https://github.com/kevinongko/vue-numeric).

Every time I need it, I always use at least this classes and attributes.

```
<vue-numeric
   class="form-control border-input text-right"
   :separator="."
   :minus=false
/>
```

Is it possible to declare some of the attributes when registering the component, so that I don't need to type it each time I need vue-numeric?

And also that maybe one day I decided to change the class, I just need to change it in 1 file, e.g in main.js. I don't want to change it from node_modules.

I would like to do something like this.

```
Vue.component('vue-numeric', VueNumeric, {
   class:"form-control border-input text-right",
   separator:".",
   minus: false
}
```

so then in template, I just need to add some specific attributes.

```
<vue-numeric v-model="price" :min=0 />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a functional wrapper component which applies the default prop values:

```es6
Vue.component('vue-numeric-default', {
  functional: true,
  render(h, ctx) {
    return h('vue-numeric', Object.assign({}, ctx.data, {
      // Apply default class only if no class was defined
      staticClass: ctx.data.class || ctx.data.staticClass
        ? ctx.data.staticClass
        : 'form-control border-input text-right',

      // Apply default props
      props: Object.assign({
        separator: '.',
        minus: false,
      }, ctx.props),
    }), ctx.children);
  },
});
```

You could also use

```
{ separator: '.', ...ctx.props }
```

syntax instead of

```
Object.assign({ separator: '.' }, ctx.props)
```

if it is supported.

Comment: Seems promising, I'm trying it

Comment: It works like a charm. And you even add info about object spread operator. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the classes in component's root element. And apply default props in `mounted` hook.

Comment: You mean edit the component in node_modules?
It's a library that I imported with npm. And as I specify before, I don't want to change it from node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

> You can define the default value to the props methods in a component and if you
> want to override it must be called it else it has the default value,
>
> you should add below code to the "vue-numeric" component file

```
props: {
   class: {
      type: String,
      default: 'form-control border-input text-right'
   },
   separator: {
     type: String,
     default: '.'
   }
   minus: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a library that I imported with npm. I don't want to change the original components in node_modules, because it wouldn't be available to my teammates that clone the project from git, and the code will be gone if the components updated via npm update.